# Help With PHPmyAdmin Install - No User Privildeges

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Using PHPMyAdmin in a Ubuntu desktop test server box that I have just installed with the rest of LAMP stack and when I use PHPmyAdmin and it says that I have no privelidges.

Is there any thing that I can do to get over this problem.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySQL command line to grant permissions to a given user if you know at least the root password.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

You can check out the [Ubuntu community docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) about how to do this and other configuration  for a LAMP server. About halfway down the page they discuss MySQL specifically and how to set it up/configure it via command line.

Answer (score 0):

Check/reset user's permissions and don't forgot to flush their cache.

This isn't programmatically question though